# How can I set the agent image order on GIS map

Tags: image, gis, anylogic, agent

I am working on a supply chain network using the GIS map. The problem I am facing is the order of images on the map. As I create them from a database, I first create Stores, then DCs, and after then Trucks (inside of each DC agent). However, Stores are on top, then DCs, and then Trucks. How can I change the image order?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the drawing stacking sequence by amending the agent population presentations. Find them on Main (where your GIS map is), right-click them and order them as needed:

[image]

Best put the animations temporarily above each other so you can stack them as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already did that. On the map, they are ordered correctly (Truck>Warehouse>Store) but when I add them using the constructor, It does the complete reverse.

Comment: You need to manually do that via code, see https://anylogic.help/anylogic/presentation/editing-presentation-shapes.html#changing-stacking-order-position